# taddrinfo ENOTFOUND your-prox

Tags: reactjs

C:\Users\Administrator>npx create-react-app james
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/;/create-react-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND your-proxy-server
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-02-05T21_06_25_638Z-debug-0.log

i want to create a react app

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.